# View is not loading on button click

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have created loginView using swiftUI, but I am not able to load another view.
From my `loginView`, I am trying to load `HomeFeedView` when I'm clicking a button. It's not working at all.

```
//
//  LoginView.swift


import SwiftUI

var screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds

struct LoginView: View {
    @State var username: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack {
                Color("light_blue")                    
                Image("logo_splash")
                VStack(spacing: 2) {
                    TextField("Email/Username", text: $username)
                    SecureField("Password", text: $password)

                    
                    Button(action: {
                            self.loginAction(username: username, password: password)}, label: {
                                    OrangeButtonView(buttonTitle: "Login")
                    })
                    
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
    func loginAction(username: String, password: String) {
        HomeFeedView()
    }
}

struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginView()
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint so, I know that I am reaching `HomeFeedView`. `HomeFeedView` is very basic.

```
HomeFeedView

struct HomeFeedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            Text("Home Feed")
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a NavigationLink, currently you are not presenting your `HomeFeedView` You can read more about NavigationViews here https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/216/complete-guide-to-navigationview-in-swiftui

Comment: You have adopted a *procedural* approach.  That isn't how SwiftUI works.  it is *declarative*.  You are creating an instance of `HomeFeedView` which is why your breakpoint fires, but it isn't in the view hierarchy. You could use a navigation view as Andrew suggested or a [router view](https://betterprogramming.pub/routing-in-swiftui-1dc87b7a47c7) approach.  This may be more appropriate in this case since you probably don't want to navigate back to login once you are logged in